# I need to disable reverse path filtering in linux to set net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter to 0 (net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2)

Tags: linux, sysctl

I need to disable reverse path filtering in Linux. I tried like this

```
 root@user:/home/user# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
```

now I like to know how to make above settings active so reverse path filtering is disabled do I need to restart sysctl or some thing, Can anyone please tell this

I tried like above but when I ran the `sysctl -system`

I get this

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter": Invalid argument
```

why this invalid argument message and I tried changing it to `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0` but it still printing `sysctl -system` as

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
along with message
```

Comment: my kernel version is `5.13.0-22-generic`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you've confused,

First, it's `sysctl --system` not `sysctl -system` to reload your configuration files; but that may just be a typo in the question.

Second, when you use `sysctl -w` to change any setting, that `-w` means writing in the *"write instead of readout"*-sense, not in the *"write to file"*-sense. It would only affect the currently active configuration, and it wouldn't be saved anywhere.

So when you run `sysctl --system` to reload the system configurationfiles, you undo your prior `sysctl -w` action.

---

Third, you're presumably trying to change the effective `rp_filter` value on your system, but the `default` part of the `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter` key, means it affects the default value for any unnamed network device that gets created *after* this point.

Presumably, your network device already exists, which means it already has its own personal `rp_filter` setting, and it doesn't care about the `default` anymore. If your network device is called `eth0`, then `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter` is likely the value you actually wanted to change (with `sysctl -w` *or*, by writing that into one of the `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf`-style configuration files and then rebooting or reloading the `--system`).

In addition to the `default` and `eth0` (or whatever yours is called),
there is also an `all` version; which is like a wildcard that affects all the *existing* variants (eg: `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2`). When your sysctl configuration is loaded during bootup, the networkdevices may or may not exist yet at the time your sysctl configuration is parsed, so it could easily vary if `eth0` does or does not exist yet at that time.
If it did exist already then the `eth0` and `all` variants would result in the desired affect and the `default` variant would not. If however the device didn't exist yet, then it's actually the other way around, and `default` is the one which would work as intended.

To be sure, just change them all/both; in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` files.

---

Update.

Ok, so since you're using a virtual networking device `tun0`, which gets created later on, going for the `default` key actually wasn't a mistake.

The main thing still holds though, you do **not** want to use both `sysctl -w` and `sysctl --system` together, as the later undoes what the former did.

It sounds like you either want something like:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0 ;
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0    ;
```

or

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter ;
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter    ;
```

Or alternatively, use the `.conf` files; then you *can* use `--system` to reload them.

Comment: I like to apply this change `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0`, tun0 interface which gets created after one of my programs start running.So assume I ran the program and my `tun0` interface gets created  then now if I type `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0` then I ran `sysctl --system` command its not not working.I am still getting reverse path filtering behavior so I like 2 know if there anything I can do after running command `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0` & `sysctl --system` commands to make sure that reverse path filtering is disabled for my tun0 interface

Comment: I've added a response/update in the answer above.

Comment: do I need to run `sysctl --system` after running command `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter;`

Comment: No, that may undo it again, depending on whats in your system configuration.